# How does Rust pattern matching determine if the bound variable will be a reference or a value?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

```
use crate::List::{Cons, Nil};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum List {
    Cons(i32, Foo),
    Nil,
}

impl List {
    fn tail(&self) -> Option<&Foo> {
        match self {
            Cons(_, item) => Some(item), // why `item` is of type `&Foo`?
            Nil => None,
        }
    }
}
```

As stated in the comment, why is `item` of type `&Foo`? What is the rule that says `item` will be type `&Foo` rather than `Foo`?

I understand that it does not make sense for item to be `Foo`; `&self` says `self` is a reference, so it does not make sense to move a value out of a reference, but are there any specifications that define the rules clearly?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for your reply. Actually RefCell  is unrelated to what I am trying to ask. Removed RefCell to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[RFC 2005 (a.k.a. *match ergonomics*)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2005-match-ergonomics.md) introduced the rule.

Before the change was implemented, there were 2 ways to write this `match`.

1. Match on `self` and prefix each pattern with `&` to "destructure" the reference.

   ```
   fn tail(&self) -> Option<&Foo> {
       match self {
           &Cons(_, ref item) => Some(item),
           &Nil => None,
       }
   }
   ```
2. Match on `*self` and don't prefix each pattern with `&` (because `*self` is not a reference).

   ```
   fn tail(&self) -> Option<&Foo> {
       match *self {
           Cons(_, ref item) => Some(item),
           Nil => None,
       }
   }
   ```

Yet, in both cases, we need to write `ref item`, otherwise we'll get `error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content`.

However, in the `match` you've written, the expression being matched is a reference (type `&List`) but the patterns are not reference patterns (as in 1. above). This is where match ergonomics kick in: the rule says that when a reference is matched with a non-reference pattern, the bindings within that pattern bind by reference rather than by value (i.e. as if they were prefixed with `ref`).