# How are tuples inside of Arcs destructured with references?

Tags: rust, tuples, destructuring, reference-counting

I'm looking at the [`Condvar` example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Condvar.html#examples) and am curious how the tuples `pair` and `pair2` are destructured:

```rust
let pair = Arc::new((Mutex::new(false), Condvar::new()));
let pair2 = pair.clone();
// ...

thread::spawn(move|| {
    let &(ref lock, ref cvar) = &*pair2;
    // ...
}
```

Doesn't `Arc`'s [`Deref` implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/sync.rs.html#772-779) return a reference to the inner data? But removing the `&` from `pair2`:

```rust
let &(ref lock, ref cvar) = *pair2;
```

gives a compiler error:

```
11 |     let &(ref lock, ref cvar) = *pair2;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected tuple, found reference
   |
   = note: expected type `(std::sync::Mutex<bool>, std::sync::Condvar)`
              found type `&_`
```

This seems to imply that `*pair2` returns a tuple and not a reference.

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Why is the return type of Deref::deref itself a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31624743/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: It's hard to answer multiple questions made in one post. Please separate them into multiple questions so that we can help you better and so that your questions will help others in the future that have one of the same questions as you!

Comment: It looks like your second question ("why do these variants work") might be answered by the answers of [How does Rust pattern matching determine if the bound variable will be a reference or a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56511328/155423); [Is there any difference between matching on a reference to a pattern or a dereferenced value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43370054/155423); [How can the ref keyword be avoided when pattern matching in a function taking &self or &mut self?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55130932/155423).

Comment: You can go one step further: `let (lock, cvar) = &*pair;`

Comment: Hi @Shepmaster, thanks for the quick response! Let me take some time to digest the links that you gave.

Comment: Hi again @Shepmaster, I've taken a stab at splitting, editing, and answering this question. The other half is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57128842/8807809).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, `Deref` returns a reference but this reference is still dereferenced by `*`.

Before deciphering `&*pair`, first look at `*pair` in detail.

`Arc` implements the `Deref` trait, so the Rust compiler essentially transforms:

```rust
*pair
```

into

```rust
*(pair.deref())
```

`Arc::deref()` does return a reference but this will be dereferenced by `*`, resulting in a tuple.

The `Condvar` example adds a leading `&` because it only needs to borrow the tuple that `*pair` yields.

Also see:

- [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31624743/8807809) on `Deref::deref`
- The [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#treating-a-type-like-a-reference-by-implementing-the-deref-trait).