# How are Tuples destructured into references?

Tags: rust, tuples, destructuring

I'm looking at the [`Condvar` example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Condvar.html#examples) and am curious how the tuples `pair` and `pair2` are destructured:

```rust
let pair = Arc::new((Mutex::new(false), Condvar::new()));
let pair2 = pair.clone();
// ...

thread::spawn(move|| {
    let &(ref lock, ref cvar) = &*pair2;
    // ...
}
```

Removing the `&` from `pair2`:

```rust
let &(ref lock, ref cvar) = *pair2;
```

gives a compiler error as I expected:

```
11 |     let &(ref lock, ref cvar) = *pair2;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected tuple, found reference
   |
   = note: expected type `(std::sync::Mutex<bool>, std::sync::Condvar)`
              found type `&_`
```

However, it seems to compile and run fine if the `&` around the tuple is removed:

```rust
let (ref lock, ref cvar) = &*pair2;
```

or if both of the `&`'s are removed:

```rust
let (ref lock, ref cvar) = *pair2;
```

or even with

```rust
let (lock, cvar) = &*pair2;
```

Is the compiler is helping us in the latter cases?

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is helping us using [match ergonomics](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2005-match-ergonomics.html). Match ergonomics applies to tuple destructuring and the `match` expression; we'll look at the case of the `match` expression first.

Match ergonomics simplifies how Rust binds variables when a *reference* is matched to a *non-reference pattern*:

```rust
let x = Some(42);
let x_ref = &x;

match x_ref { // <-- reference match expression: `x_ref`
    Some(a) => {}, // <-- non-reference pattern: `Some(a)`
    None => {},
}
```

Older version of the Rust compiler didn't allow this. Instead, one had to either specify references (`&`) in the pattern:

```rust
// Old Rust
match x_ref {
    &Some(a) => {},
    &None => {},
}
```

or dereference before matching:

```rust
// Old Rust
match *x_ref {
    Some(a) => {},
    None => {},
}
```

Notice that `a` owns the `Option`'s inner value, which is problematic for non-`Copy` types. To avoid this, one also had to borrow the inner value. This is done by binding `a` as a reference using the `ref` keyword:

```rust
// Old Rust
let x = Some(Box::new(42));
let x_ref = &x;

match x_ref {
    &Some(ref a) => {},
    &None => {},
}
```

or

```rust
// Old Rust
match *x_ref {
    Some(ref a) => {},
    None => {},
}
```

Rust's new match ergonomics allow a simplified version:

```rust
// New Rust
match x_ref {
    Some(a) => {
        // x_ref is automatically dereferenced
        // a is automatically bound as a reference
    },
    None => {},
}
```

for both `Copy` and non-`Copy` types.

Applying this to tuple destructuring,

```rust
let pair = Arc::new((Mutex::new(false), Condvar::new()));
let (lock, cvar) = &*pair;
//                 ^^^^^^ reference match expression
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ non-reference pattern
```

- `*pair` is a tuple
- `&*pair` is a reference to a tuple
- Both `lock` and `cvar` are bound as references

Also see these Stack Overflow posts on:

- the [matching and the ref keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55130932/8807809)
- [pattern matching on a reference or a dereferenced value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43370054/8807809)
- [binding during pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56511328/8807809)